Пишу тг бота и код выдаёт вот такую ошибку:ImportError: cannot import name 'executor' from 'aiogram'
полный код ошибки
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\marse\PycharmProjects\NFO\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
ImportError: cannot import name 'executor' from 'aiogram' (C:\Users\marse\PycharmProjects\NFO\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\__init__.py)

версия aiogram 3.8.0, всё работает, за исключением этого, помогите пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен

По вашему вопросу полно схожих тем, достаточно воспользоваться поиском

После обновления больше нету executor, вот и выдаёт вам ошибку.
Вот где описано это
